# why is 100% width displaying outside the view port?

Tags: css

On [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/example.html), I have a block of 6 boxes:

- Who We Are
- Where We Are
- What We Do
- How We Do It
- Why We Do It
- Case Studies

[image]

When we reduce the view port to narrower than 1160px, this area stays at 1160px wide.

I have the following CSS:

```
.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_col-sm-12 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1160px) {
    .bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_col-sm-12 {
        float: none;
        width: 100vw;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-50vw;
    }   
}
```

Why is the `width: 100%;` not being respected below view port 1160px?

Comment: It's harder to tell without more context, but I'll bet that there's something inside the container that isn't shrinking, and thus the parent container stays the same large size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `display: table;` on `.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width`

To fix it, use the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1160px) {
    .bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_col-sm-12 {
        float: none;
        width: 100vw;
        display: block;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see on line no. 42. There is fixed `width:1140px;`. Which is causing problem. You can replce with `max-width`.

```
.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner{
    width: 1140px;
}
```

to

```
.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner{
     max-width: 1140px;
 }
```

or

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1160px) {
  .bouble_shaded_bg_full-width.vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner{
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Also on line no. 73 `.site-inner, .content-sidebar-wrap` have fixed `width:1160`. Which is also not good it will give horizontal scroll it is not visible because of `.site-container` `overflow:hodden`. You can do it max-width or control by media queries.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This property is `inherit` that means you have to define 'box-sizing: border-box' When you are using padding. In bootstrap they just simply apply `box-sizing: border-box` to everything. ('box-sizing' is just an observation not an issue.)